# -webkit-transition/-moz-transition vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, animation, webkit, mozilla

This is a two-part question:

What applied style takes priority: a `-webkit-transition` rule in CSS or a similar `$.css()` method in jQuery?

Is there any point to including a `-webkit-transition` rule in my stylesheet if I am also using the `.css` method in jQuery? That is, will adding `-webkit-transition` make the animation any more efficient in Safari/Webkit browsers  if I am including the jQuery rule anyways? (This goes for `-moz-transition` too).

Or is it best to use solely jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: jQuery animations don't use transitions AFAIK

Comment: One jQuery plugin that can take care of things for you (without having to edit your CSS) is jQuery Transit. http://ricostacruz.com/jquery.transit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I say its good to use both even if they do the same. If someone comes along with javascript disabled, there is good chance they will still see the intended transitions via CSS if they are on latest browsers to supports transitions and such. Just my point of thought on this.

Edit: Okay, so my droopy eyes mistook the question as CSS or JQuery. But still, would be nice idea to do it in CSS file and JQuery animation. No real benefit I see to do webkit in JQuery.css

Comment: JavaScript. They aren't even close to the same thing. Please, for the love of God, learn this.

Comment: Well excuse me there. When I said the same, i meant the animation would look the same or closely alike. JQuery's animation and CSS transition, the normal user would not know if it's CSS or JQuery when the programmer can get it to look closely identical.

Comment: I know that's what you meant. I'm just trying to let you know that Java and JavaScript aren't the same thing. :)

Comment: I know that, but if the browser has disabled java, then the user wouldn't be seeing any Jquery is what I am saying.

Comment: If they disabled Java, jQuery would work perfectly. I don't even have Java installed and jQuery works perfectly. jQuery is a JavaScript library, it has nothing to do with Java at all.

Comment: wow, doesn't work for me when I disable Java in chrome or firefox.

Comment: Does to me. JQuery is built on java ;)

Comment: "jQuery is a fast and concise **JavaScript** Library"
Straight from jQuery's website.

Comment: I have spent the last three years of my life working closely with jQuery on many different projects. I think I know what language it's written in.

Comment: Okay JavaScript, no one is talking about java applet or java language here. Anyway, my only point is JQuery does not and has not ever worked for me when chrome and firefox disabled java. But if it works for you, then you's got some magic

Comment: @robx: You are disabling JavaScript, not just Java. jQuery has no relationship to Java.

Comment: Yes, i did say disable java in chrome and firefox, not java itself for the OS. I guess you guys are taking java as in java itself on the OS, but the topic itself was about JQuery (javascript), and so when i say java, i mean javascript in the browser itself. Why would I bother with disable system java to test web apps?

Comment: What is going on here. My apologies to everyone. Guess my nephew was on last night wanting to help others haha.

Comment: Haha, you need to have a chat to your nephew then and convince them that java and javascript are completely different and to stop referring to them both as java.

Comment: I intend to do so. I can't believe he did just that after we already had this exact same debate not too long ago. Some people are just stubborn.

Comment: ARE YOU DISABLING JAVA OR NOT? I'm so confused.

Comment: Sorry sorry, my nephew was wanting to help here. I am sure he means javascript and not java. I have not taught him java since he does not need to know java to program javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what rule you are using, the native browser CSS equivalent would be the better choice, since it could be hardware accelerated.

It looks like [Chrome 9+](http://dropshado.ws/post/2857434171/chrome-gpu-accelerated-compositing-and-3d-css), Safari 5 and [Firefox 4](http://www.azarask.in/blog/post/animation-css-transitions-jquery-easy/) all support hardware accelerated CSS transforms. jQuery is catching up and it looks like it will be [hardware accelerated](https://github.com/paulirish/lazyweb-requests/issues/16) eventually.